# How can I related Web Services to SOAP and REST

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

To be honest with you I really don't get the relationship that Web Services share with SOAP and REST.

I have a very simplistic understanding of the whole topic, web services are software designed to facilitate machine-to-machine communication over a network. Web services have an interface that machines understand (WSDL). Other systems interact with a service using SOAP messages.

Where does my understanding of Web Services slip up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very brief attempt at an answer - if this doesn't do it, then please edit your question or comment to clarify what you are looking for.

SOAP is basically a protocol allowing for a platform independent way of performing RPCs or by passing one-way documents (not done nearly as often).  It is relatively procedural in nature.  You are correct that WSDL is a contract of the interface that the two pieces of software agree to communicate by (I'm careful not to say 'machine' there as you can have SOAP interaction on the same machine too.

REST itself is more of a paradigm on how we are supposed to expose and communicate with 'resources'.  I consider it a bit more OO in that everything you are dealing with is a resource (or object) exposed at a specific URL that has the same methods defined on it... the same methods established by the HTTP protocol, which basically amount to a CRUD interface.   Though there is no established contract, in the case of a WSDL with SOAP, that doesn't mean that REST 'services' don't have interfaces... they do.  They just don't have a uniform way of providing a contract for them (perhaps WADL is becoming widespread enough for this).

If you are curious about REST, I highly recommend giving ["RESTful WebServices" by Ruby and Richardson](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260) a read.

Comment: Good answer. I don't see WADL however becoming widespread. It has been available for some time, but there is no uptake. Also, REST works be exchanging documents, and the media types (former MIME types) represent the contract for such services.

Answer (score 1):

**Web services**

As you described web services are software for machine-to-machine communication. I would only append that one of the main purpose of web services is interoperability = cross platform communication.

**WSDL**

WSDL stands for Web Services Description (or Definition) Language. It is XML based language which describes interface (contract) of the service.

**SOAP**

SOAP stands for Simple Object Access protocol. It is standardized interoperable protocol for machine-to-machine communication. In SOAP service you develop set of methods which allow you to execute code remotely. Only SOAP services can be described by first versions of WSDL. There are multiple types of SOAP web services. Multiple interoperable standards (WS-*) add additional features to SOAP services like message security, distributed transactions, reliable messaging, etc. SOAP can be used over different transport protocols but most common is SOAP over HTTP.

**REST**

REST stands for Representational Entity State Transfer. REST is not a protocol. It is development approach / philosophy. In REST services you have small set of methods and you use them to work with resources identified by URI. These methods are most commonly HTTP GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. REST services can only be described by [WSDL 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/) (the problem is that WSDL 2.0 is not yet supported by all platforms). Because of different nature of REST services, description is not needed and most of the time not used at all. REST services are used only over HTTP protocol.

Comment: I have the feeling that on the latest version of WSDL you could use REST?

Comment: @JHarley: You are right. I just checked it and WSDL 2.0 can describe REST. I will modify may answer. The problem is that WSDL 2.0 is not yet supported on all platforms.

Comment: REST does not need WSDL 2.0 support and is "supported" on all platforms that support HTTP. In fact, most of the existing REST web services don't support WSDL 2.0 at all.

Comment: @Muhammad: Thanks you are absolutely right. I added it to my answer.